# SQL join return rows when Where not satisfied

Tags: sql-server, join, null

I have a table of `Monkeys` and a table of `Trees` with a many-to-many relationship joined by a third `MonkeysTrees` FK Table.

I have this query that returns all the Monkeys and Trees for a given Tree `Id`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Monkeys m
JOIN MonkeysTrees mt ON mt.MonkeyId = m.Id
join Trees t ON t.Id=mt.TreeId
WHERE t.Id = 1;
```

If I change `t.Id` in the final `WHERE` clause to an `Id` that isn't in the Trees table, I'd still like to return a table containing all the Monkeys, but with NULL in the joined fields. How could I do that?

Comment: what does `null` in the joined fields mean?

Comment: If the WHERE is not satisfied, no rows are returned. I'd still like to return all the Monkeys, but with null Trees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an outer join, the position of the on clauses below yields `Monkeys left join (MonkeysTrees inner join Trees where treeid = 1)`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Monkeys m
LEFT JOIN MonkeysTrees mt
           INNER JOIN Trees t ON t.Id=mt.TreeId AND t.Id = 1
ON mt.MonkeyId = m.Id
```